# Turn numpy array into an xarray in Python

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have the following numpy array of shape (3,2,3)

```
a = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],[[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]])
a.shape
```

I would like to turn this into an xarray and give it names: income (values = 0,1,2), sex (values=0,1) and BMI (values = ('low', 'med', 'high')

How would I go about doing this?

Thx

Comment: Haven't you found anything the `xarray` docs to help you?  An open ended question like this lets us assume the worse about what you haven't read or tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define the names in the dims attribute

import xarray as xr

import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],[[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]])

data = xr.DataArray(a, dims=("income", "sex","BMI"))